# Accessing the internet on a google cloud virtual machine through a VPN

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, openvpn

I have a virtual instance in google cloud and would like to use OpenVPN to access the internet, from the machine. However, when I start OpenVPN on the machine, I lose control of it. My guess is because there is a change in the external IP address, the communication protocols set up with the machine no longer work.

I have minimal knowledge about networks and would appreciate any help.

Comment: can you explain why doyou need to use openVPN and how it is configured?

Comment: The external IP is not changed by OpenVPN. Most likely Open VPN changed the VM's routing configuration breaking existing connections. You might need to configure a second network adapter for your VM so that OpenVPN can manage one network and you can connect via the other. A good answer will require understanding what OpenVPN is connecting to, the routes required so see if it is even possible.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install) implementation would be easier, basically all you need is to download that on your VPN server, run it and download the `.ovpn` file and you are good to go, just open any GCP Firewall port you want to use for your OpenVPN server.